# SQL fetch multiple values on join

Tags: sql

Hi I have an SQL table which has two tables which make reference to the same foreign key in a separate table twice... something like

SALES table

```
idSales idClient1 idClient2
1       1         2
```

CLIENT table

```
idClient ClientName
1        Bob
2        Mick
```

I want to join the SALES table to the CLIENT table and return data as follows:

```
idSales idClientClientName1 idClientClientName2
1       Bob                 Mick
```

Can anyone help with the SQL for this? I'm getting ambiguous column name errors on my join.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to basically join table `Client` on table `Sales` twice because there are two columns on table `Sales` that are dependent on table `Client`.

```
SELECT  a.idSales,
        b.ClientName ClientName1,
        c.ClientName ClientName2
FROM    Sales a
        INNER JOIN Client b
            ON a.idClient1 = b.idClient
        INNER JOIN Client c
            ON a.idClient2 = c.idClient
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

But when one of the columns or both columns are *nullable*, `INNER JOIN` will not give you all records from `Sales` because it will only select where it has atleast one match on the other table. Instead use `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

I might add that in cases like this, I use table aliases that hint at what entity you are linking to in the joined table.  If for example, the foreign keys were to an address table, and you had a `work` address, and a `Home` address,  I would use tables aliases of `h` and `w` for the two joins.   In your case, i.e.,

```
Selext s.idSales,
    c1.ClientName ClientName1,
    c2.ClientName ClientName2
From Sales s
    Join Client c1
        On c1.idClient = s.idClient1
    Join Client c2
        On c2.idClient = s.idClient2
```

Answer (score 0):

For those beginner SQL folks who may see this question in the future, it's helpful to add in the AS words, it makes it clearer still:

```
SELECT
Sale.idSales,
c1.ClientName AS ClientName1,
c2.ClientName AS ClientName2
FROM
Sales AS Sale
INNER JOIN Client AS c1 ON Sale.idClient1 = c1.idClient
INNER JOIN Client AS c2 ON Sale.idClient2 = c2.idClient
```